# Setting Dissector for Multicast Messages With Lua

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

Is there a way to set up a dissector in Lua to listen for a multicast address instead of a specific port?

Right now I have:

```
udp_table:add(MY_PORT, MYPROTO)
```

but the data I am sending is going out over multicast and so the port as far as I can tell is unknown until it is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you learn the port, you can use Wireshark's *"Decode as"* feature to cause Wireshark to decode the packets sent to that learned port as "`MYPROTO`".

The easiest way to do that is to right-click on one of the multicast packets and choose *"Decode as..."*.  A dialog window will appear where you can select your protocol from the drop-down list to be associated with the learned port.